# How to install lamina / aleph to Clojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, lamina-clojure

Currently, I use Leiningen 2.1.3 on Java 1.6.0_45

Clojure 1.5.1 connected LightTable IDE 0.4.11

I want to install [lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina), but looking at Installation-

[lamina "0.5.0-rc3"]

doesn't make sense to me since I'm fairly new.

Please advice how to install, and some good resource for the library management system.

Thanks!

Comment: Is https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen helpful?

Comment: In fact, http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/libs-management-and-use.html more helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add that line to the `:dependencies` section of your project.clj file so it looks something like this:

```
...
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [lamina "0.5.0-rc3"]]
...
```

Then, use it in wherever you need it:

```
(ns myproj.core
  (:require [lamina.core :as lamina]))
```

This would make it so you call the channel function like this: `(lamina/channel 1 2 3)`

Or in the repl:

```
user=> (use 'lamina.core)
nil
user=> (def ch (channel 1 2 3))
#'user/ch
user=> ch
<== [1 2 3 …]
```

Comment: Thanks. I read http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/libs-management-and-use.html and understood how lein manage the library. Your answer is concise, too.